# Set System Time and Date iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning IOS app development. I was wondering if I can change system date and time from my own iOS app. I know that I can't use that functionality if I am submitting the app, but I was curious and wanted to try out.

Comment: Why not have a global date variable? `var currentDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: ...)`

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can do that on a non jailbroken device.